# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_data_validation' in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, google-colaboratory

I tried to import Tensorflow Data Validation library via the below command in Google Colab.

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
```

It gave me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_data_validation'
```

I tried to install the library using pip via below commands. But couldn't install the package successfully.

```
 pip install tensorflow-data-validation

 pip install tensorflow-data-validation==1.3.0

 pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-data-validation[all]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

To install the library properly, follow these steps:

1. Install the library using pip:

   ```
   !pip install tensorflow-data-validation
   ```
2. Reload the environment. A button will show up at the end of the previous cell to `Restart`, but you can also do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or using the menu: "Runtime" > "Restart Runtime".
3. Import the library as usual:

   ```
   import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
   ```

**Why do I need to reload the environment?** It's because installing `tensorflow-data-validation` upgrades one of the libraries already present in your Colab environment. So, to "activate" the new environment and use the newly installed libraries and their installed versions you need to reload the environment

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem with Google Vertex AI (which is the same as Colab in this context). I've spent 6 hours and the only solution I can come up with is this:

```
# Cell 1
!pip install pyarrow==10.0.1
!pip install numpy==1.19.2
!pip install tensorflow-data-validation --user

# Restart Kernel

# Cell 2
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
import sys
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

print('Installing TensorFlow Data Validation')
!pip install -q tensorflow_data_validation[visualization]

print('TFDV version: {}'.format(tfdv.version.__version__))
# Confirm that we're using Python 3
assert sys.version_info.major is 3, 'Oops, not running Python 3. Use Runtime > Change runtime type'
```

I don't know enough to tell you why this is happening, but I suspect that when you install it as `--user` and that will allow Python to not roll back the update when it fails.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this error by installing tensorflow_data_validation library via the below command. Now I'm able to use this library in my Colab file.

```
!pip install -U tensorflow \
            tensorflow-data-validation \
            apache-beam[gcp]
```

Comment: Hi Sanushi, I have been having the same issue in Python 3.9. Did you manage to install it using the above line in 3.9?